# Test private members of a object in scala

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

Here is the object:

```
package object beautifier {
  private val scientificPattern = """([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?""".r
}
```

And the test:

import org.scalatest._
import vu.co.kaiyin.formatting.scientificNotaion.beautifier.scientificPattern

```
class ScientificNotationSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Regex" should "return correct matches" in {
    "-4.2e-3" match {
      case scientificPattern(coef, _, _, exponent) => {
        coef should be (-4.2)
        exponent should be (-3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I got an error of course:

```
Error:(2, 8) object scientificPattern is not a member of package vu.co.kaiyin.formatting.scientificNotaion.beautifier
import vu.co.kaiyin.formatting.scientificNotaion.beautifier.scientificPattern
       ^
```

How do I solve this problem?